# Short story with a scientist going into the future he looked at with a drone, and returning with a humanity-killing creature on him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I remember reading (maybe half a decade ago) a short story in an anthology featuring time travel.

The story followed a group of scientists sending a drone to the future and watching the video of the future afterwards. They started getting puzzled as each time they sent the drone, it returned with a video of a worse future.

> In the future they start seeing hordes of "alien" creatures that kill every trace of humanity. One of the scientists eventually decides to go himself, and when he comes back to the present, he has one of the creatures with him.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's a Philip K. Dick short story, "[Meddler](https://philipkdickreview.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/meddler/)" (1954). The "aliens" are butterflies that lay eggs on the time machine.

A description of the ending:

> Hasten explains what he learned. The butterflies only attack humans, and leave other living things along. Wood is confident that with this knowledge humans can stop the butterflies. A soldier notices that the Time Car has many cocoons, most of which are already empty. The butterflies have been released into the present.

Comment: Yes I thought it was butterflies but wasn't sure about it !

Comment: @XGouchet There appears to be a movie adaptation in the wild.